# Why does minikube service run cluster on localhost with random IP, but never shows up on minikube_IP with pre-defined nodePort?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

Now here are the details:

1. I'm running minikube on WSL2 Ubuntu app (5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2):

```
$ lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
  Release:        20.04
  Codename:       focal
```

2. My minikube VM's driver: `--driver=docker`.

Whenever I run the `minikube service` command, my web app is automatically opened on my browser at the localhost URL with a random port number different from the port number specified on my service configuration file.

After starting minikube and successfully creating deployment and service with configuration files, when I run:

```
$ minikube service demo-app-service -n demo-app
```

I get the following output:

```
|-----------------|------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
|    NAMESPACE    |      NAME        | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------------|------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| demo-app        | demo-app-service |          80 | http://192.168.49.2:30021 |
|-----------------|------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Starting tunnel for service demo-app-service.
|-----------------|------------------|-------------|------------------------|
|    NAMESPACE    |      NAME        | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------------|------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| demo-app        | demo-app-service |             | http://127.0.0.1:38243 |
|-----------------|------------------|-------------|------------------------|
  Opening service demo-app/demo-app-service in default browser...
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on linux, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

First, my local browser opens up automatically and I am able to access my demo app on the localhost URL (http://127.0.0.1:38243), but the port number seems to be randomly assigned as it keeps changing every time I rerun the `minikube service` command to deploy the same app.

Secondly, my main concern is that the demo app is never reachable at `minikube_IP:nodePort` (http://192.168.49.2:30021) on my local browser. This is the same `nodePort` I defined on my service configuration file, and the `minikube_IP` is the same IP minikube returns when I run

```
$ minikube ip
```

However, when I execute

```
$ minikube service demo-app-service -n demo-app --url
```

the output only provides the localhost URL with a new random port number (http://127.0.0.1:<random_portNumber>).

According to minikube's [official documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-service-with-tunnel), it was stated that,

"The network is limited if using the Docker driver on Darwin, Windows, or WSL, and the Node IP is not reachable directly."

However, I was hoping this issue may have been resolved by now or maybe there is a workaround it. I have also tried installing VirtualBox as `--driver` but it just doesn't work.

Please any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I kept running into errors trying to install `google-chrome` on WSL2. Eventually, I had to resort to using the port-forwarding cmd:

```
kubectl port-forward service/demo-app-service 30021:80 -n demo-app
```

With this, I can access my app at my pre-defined node port number (http://localhost:30021) which works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the Google Chrome for Linux on wsl:

Change directories into the temp folder: cd /tmp
Use wget to download it: sudo wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Get the current stable version: sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Fix the package: sudo apt install --fix-broken -y
Configure the package: sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
To launch, enter: google-chrome